# iOS: Is there a way to make a viewcontroller look inactive by having everything grayed out?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I want my ViewController and every object appear inactive by having it all grayed out (kind of like how the UIAlertView popup grays out everything in the background). I do not want to have to manually gray out every object there is.Is there an easy way to make this work?

Comment: Do you want it to be inactive, or only to appear to be inactive?

Comment: recurse. For view in subviews gray out subviews... if you know recursion this will work for each. Except for complex views like buttons, use a isKindOf test or isMember class function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIView *grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
[self.view addSubview:grayView];
```

You can mess with the white and alpha values to get exactly what you want, but that should put a gray tint over everything in your view controller's view.

Comment: This seems like a good solution especially because it would not only make everything "look inactive" (per the question) but it would also disable interaction.

Comment: This only works if your view controller is not in a UINavigationController or UITabBarController. This will cover the view, but the nav bar will not be "covered". You will want to add the view to the nav controller view: `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:grayView]` and set the view bounds to the main screen to fill the screen: `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`

Comment: @Corey I think better will be `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];`  because applicationFrame is the screen size minus the size of the status bar (if visible).

Answer (score 2):

As Patrick Goley pointed with his good answer - just put a gray `UIView` with alpha between 0.5 - 0.75 above your original view. But this method will disable all the user interactions with its subviews (buttons,etc). If you want to preserve user interactions with the elements but nevertheless mark the view as "inactive", you should subclass the view which you will put above your original view (which you want to mark as inactive) and in this subclass override this method:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

// Original "inactive" UIView will now respond to touch events if return NO:

  return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will cover also any parent controller: UINavigationController | UITabBarController.
Don't forget #import "AppDelegate.h".

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];    
UIView *grayView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appDelegate.window.bounds] autorelease];
grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:0.8];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:grayView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

Set the alpha of the view

```
[self.view setAlpha:0.5];
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? A reason should be given especially since this seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: At the least, it needs to either be `setAlpha:` or `.alpha = `.

Comment: I didn't downvote but there are two problems. 1) As Kevin points out the code is wrong. 2) Setting the view controller's view to be partially transparent is not the correct look. Colors from behind the view controller will bleed through.

Comment: hey Maddy, as of iOS 7 that's the "standard way to do it"... also bad code, I don't see as a reason to downvote IF the meaning is clear. I do see this as a valid answer myself. To say this is not "A way to do it" is like saying there's only one way to draw a diagram.

Comment: also I do agree with most of what you said, my explanations were generalities. Referring to iOS 7 bleed-through at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add a UIView that has a black background, and then lower the alpha.

```
UIView *grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
grayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[grayView setAlpha:0.65];
```

And then do not forget to add the subview to your main view

```
[self.view addSubView:grayView];
```