# Screen overlay not covering entire screen in iOS after seguing back from Dashboard to Home Page

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding a gray UIView overlay on the screen [in the view's custom controller class].  It's not covering the entire screen when it segues from the dashboard back to the home screen.  When I call the overlay on the home screen it will cover it all properly

```
        UIView *grayOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];           
        [grayOverlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.9]];
        [self.view addSubview:grayOverlay];
```

edit:  Maybe this is what I need to do:[iOS: Is there a way to make a viewcontroller look inactive by having everything grayed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710749/ios-is-there-a-way-to-make-a-viewcontroller-look-inactive-by-having-everything)

Comment: What is `self` when it doesn't cover the entire screen? Do you have a `UINavigationController` or a `UITabBarViewController` involved? What's the purpose of the gray overlay?

Comment: It is a UIViewController.  It's weird because it will cover the iPad screen entirely after seguing.  It only appears to be not covering it for the iPhone 5s.  The gray overlay appears while the user is logging in.

Comment: It sounds like you might be doing something that I've solved by using MBProgressHUD, an open source library on GitHub. If you check it out, look into the `dimsBackground` property. Let me know if that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIView *grayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Worked as opposed to "self.view.frame", which is weird because it was only on the 5s it wasn't covering it when it segued back...

*shrugs*